# Access cells of a raster layer in R

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-raster

I am totally new to spatial analysis and I have a question regarding raster layers in R.
I'm working with the following libraries:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
```

I have a raster layer which represent a climatic variable on a certain geographical region and I have some vectors which represent points in this region.

How can I check whether two points are in the same cell of the raster layer?
I know how to extract the climatic value at each point, but I have no clue how get the cell containing a certain point.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

EDIT: The points were given in coordinates (namely each point consist of a vector with the coordinates of the point). All the coordinates were stored in a CSV file, which I have converted into a `SpatialPoint` class using the function `SpatialPoint` in `library(sp)`.

Comment: Hi Onil90. Are you able to edit your question to show the format of the vectors with the points in them? Otherwise it's going to be hard to help here.

Comment: hi @AllanCameron! Sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
xy <- cbind(1:5, 1:5)
```

To get the cellnumbers of `xy` for `r`:

```
cellFromXY(r, xy)
[1] 32222 31863 31504 31145 30786
```